# Analyzing 3 Dimensional data in MS Excel

Tags: excel, graph, statistics, analytics, visualization

Need help

I have to analyze traffic violations data with respect to place, month, and type of violation in MS Excel.

I can plot graph of Month vs Count of Violation in a place that gives me place where maximum violations took place in a month

and Month vs Count of Type of Violation that tells me which violation took place maximum in a month.

But the data I want is, How to get place of violation where a certain type of violation took place maximum time in a month. This data will allow me to plan to reduce violations and improve safety.

inshort:
I can make 2d Graph of Place of Violation(50 Places) vs Month
I can make 2d Graph of Type of Violation(15 types) vs Month

But I want a 3d Graph in MS Excel that supports Place of Violation vs Type of Violation vs Month.

Can you tell me how to achieve this? if there is some method to reduce 3d data into 2d, do let me know, I can try for that. Thanks.

**Adding More info as per Comment**

Lets say I have table like this

[image: My Main Table]

Now I can plot a 2d Bar Graph Between Month vs Count of Violation Type to determine that what violations has taken place in a month and with what count.

Another Bar graph would be Month vs Count of Place of Violation to get at what places most violations have been taken place in whole month.

But I want a 3 Column comparison graph in which I want to determine, in a month, what count of violation type has happened across different places.

like a 3d array
graph[month][place][count of specific violation type]

I hope that makes it clear, if not, let me know so I can paste the actual graphs.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you run into problems.  Without examples of your data and desired output, it is hard to figure out what you are doing.  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess I have already explained as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D graphs are really hard for people to read and interpret. You might consider making a series of graphs by month (1 graph per month) if you really want to highlight monthly changes.  If you just want to find the troublespots, you could graph place by violation and be done with it.

But if you are sold on a 3D graph, you could look at pivottables and pivotcharts.  I graphed your dataset using a PivotTable with Date on the Axis Field and Violation and Place on the legend field and Count of Date for the Values.  I then selected the Date column in my PivotTable and chose Group Selection from PivotTable Tools > Options in the ribbon, and grouped by month.

The end result was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdpqC.png) monstrosity, but it sounds like that might be what you are looking for.  I included the PivotTable chart and its options so you could see the setup.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking on how to represent 3D data, Well this one will work for now.